# android: switch fragments overlapping issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a FriendActivity, onCreate i create FriendFragment and display. 
when switchFrag is call I switch to AddFriendFragment. the issue that im having is then i switch to AddFriendFragment, both fragments are overlapping. I only want to display AddFriendFragment, how should i hide FriendFragment?

```
 public class FriendActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = FriendFragment.class.getSimpleName();

    private FriendContract.Presenter mPresenter;
    public static final String EXTRA_USER_ID = "USER_ID";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_friend);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    String userId = getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_USER_ID);
    FriendFragment friendFragment = (FriendFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.friendListFrame);
    if (friendFragment == null) {
        friendFragment = FriendFragment.newInstance(userId);
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.friendListFrame, friendFragment);
        transaction.commit();
    }
    mPresenter = new FriendPresenter(userId, friendFragment, this);

}
public void switchFrag(){
    Log.i(TAG,"switch to add friend");
    String userId = getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_USER_ID);
    AddFriendFragment addFriendFragment = AddFriendFragment.newInstance(userId);
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.friendListFrame, addFriendFragment);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

}

I tried to set android:background="@android:color/white" for FrameLayout, but it did not work.
any help would be appreciated

Comment: You're doing an `add()` transaction in `switchFrag()`. Sounds like you want `replace()` instead.

Comment: try to set background for your fragment layout

Comment: set background  color to AddFriendFragment's inflate layout.

Comment: use transaction.replace(R.id.friendListFrame, friendFragment); instead of transaction.add(R.id.friendListFrame, friendFragment);